# Where is HyperTerminal in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hyperterminal

I can't find [HyperTerminal](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_terminal.mspx) to set my [COM port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29). Where is it in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean HyperTerminal, it's [no longer included](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-happened-to-HyperTerminal) in Windows 7. Use Phone and Modem Options instead:

- Open **Phone and Modem Options** by
  clicking the **Start** button, clicking
  **Control Panel**, clicking **Hardware and
  Sound**, and then clicking **Phone and
  Modem Options**.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). HyperTerminal is no more in Windows 7.

Comment: I think Putty is probably the best replacement as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking for HyperTerminal? If so, it isn't on Windows 7. Take a look at [this site](http://digitizor.com/2009/08/29/how-to-install-the-winxp-hyperterminal-client-on-windows-vista-or-windows-7-free) for the way to get the files needed and how to install it on Windows 7.