# Windows 8 opens 'moviemaker' when trying to access hyperterminal program

Tags: windows-8, file-association

How can I have my Windows 8 system recognize the `.ht` file extension to launch a hyper terminal app?

I am using an HP Envy tablet.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/choose-programs-windows-uses-default

Answer (score 0):

First, [locate](http://goo.gl/Bxt3v4) and install a HyperTerminal-compatible app, because Windows 8 doesn't come with HyperTerminal anymore (hasn't since Vista). :)

- [What happened to HyperTerminal?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/what-happened-to-hyperterminal)
- [Where is HyperTerminal in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/255518/where-is-hyperterminal-in-windows-7)

If it doesn't associate the `.ht` extension for you, then check out questions such as: [How to set the default program or application for handling a given file type or url protocol?](https://superuser.com/questions/494101/how-to-set-the-default-program-or-application-for-handling-a-given-file-type-or)